# Polyarea returns false value

Tags: matlab

```
X = [0 0 1 1];

Y = [0 1 0 1];

polyarea(X,Y)

ans  = 0
```

Here the answer should be 1 , but I got this as answer  , there  is no prob with other co ordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care of the vertices order

```
X = [0 0 1 1];
Y = [0 1 1 0];
```

should work.

Comment: yup it worked ,  thanks .... so does it apply to all figures , i mean simply giving the co-ordinates is not enough

Comment: yes, you have to give the coordinates in order because the algorithm has to connect the vertices in order to compute the area