# Polygon Area Calculations Differences Using MatLab's Polyarea to Excel's SumProduct

Tags: excel, matlab

I am calculating the area enclosed by this polygon:

[image]

Given by a set of coordinates:

```
0   2.06667
1.14815 2.06667
3.44444 2.75556
5.74074 3.44444
9.18519 3.44444
16.0741 2.75556
26.4074 1.83704
35.5926 1.14815
38.2333 0.688889
38.75   0.028704
```

I originally did this in Excel, using the `Sumproduct` [method](http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2014/06/polygon-area-shoelace-algorithm-Excel.html), and got an answer which seemed reasonable. The Excel formula I'm using is:

```
=0.5*ABS(SUMPRODUCT(F30:F39,G31:G40)-SUMPRODUCT(G30:G39,F31:F40))
```

with F30:G40:

```
0       2.06667
1.14815 2.06667
3.44444 2.75556
5.74074 3.44444
9.18519 3.44444
16.0741 2.75556
26.4074 1.83704
35.5926 1.14815
38.2333 0.688889
38.75   0.028704
0       0
```

And the **result is 87.74**.

After moving to Matlab, I started using the `polyarea` and the answer looks unreasonable. The problematic code is:

```
Shape = [ 0    2.0667; 1.1482    2.0667; 3.4444    2.7556; 5.7407    3.4444; 9.1852    3.4444; 16.0741    2.7556;26.4074    1.8370; 35.5926    1.1482; 38.2333    0.6889; 38.7500    0.0287]
C = polyarea(Shape(:,1),Shape(:,2))
```

With the returned answer:

```
C =

47.6986
```

I have tried playing around with the order of points as one answer suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29191733/3307903) as well as adding the final points into the end (can't find the link again), but that does not seem to make a whole lot of difference.

[One answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510423/3307903) using `convhull` for the maximum enclosed area, but that returned 50.34 with the `Shape` as it is currently defined.

So, my question is: **how should this calculation be performed to get the correct result**? The Excel-provided values look more correct to me based on the graph, but I am uncertain what I'm doing incorrectly in MatLab based on the help and advice I have investigated. If the error is in my Excel code, that would also be good to know.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain those codes in a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't close the polygon!

```
C = polyarea([Shape(:,1); 0],[Shape(:,2); 0])
```

> C =
>
> 87.740954125

Matlab will not assume that  (0,0) is in the polygon unless you explicitly state it!

Comment: Thanks Ander! Having the `area` graph coloured in over that region is incredibly unhelpful in that case!

Comment: just in case your polygon don't "start" on [0,0]: `C = polyarea([Shape(:,1); Shape(1,1)],[Shape(:,2); Shape(1,2)])`

Comment: Yes and no. That is already done under the hood, so that line and the one OP has will have no difference @obchardon